# VS Code settings to launch frontend and backend for debug

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to get a simple react frontend and nodejs backend up and running and debuggable in vs code.  I'm using a [compound](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_compound-launch-configurations) launch configuration to launch 'client' and 'server' together.  The nodejs backend is started automatically for me, but I always have to do an `npm start` in the console for the client for it to connect.  All the tutorials I've seen suggest that this step has to happen before running the debug configuration in vs code.  Is it not possible for vs code to start the frontend just like it does for the nodejs backend.

This is what my launch.json looks like:

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"compounds": [
    {
        "name": "Client+Server",
        "configurations": [ "Server", "Client" ]
    }
],
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Server",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/server/server.js"
    },
    {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Client",
        "url": "http://localhost:3000",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/client/src/index.js"
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had some trouble launching the debug session from beginning so I decided to start the `nodejs` server then attach the debuggers.

I found this configuration working for me.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Attach Server",
      "restart": true,
      "port": 9000
    }, {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Client",
      "port": 9001,
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/dist",
      "sourceMaps": true
    }
  ],
  "compounds": [
    {
      "name": "Attach Client+Server",
      "configurations": ["Attach Server", "Launch Client"]
    }
  ]
}
```

And here are some of the scripts I used for `package.json`.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "rollup -c -w",
    "start": "nodemon --ignore '*.ts' --inspect=9000 ./dist/server/index"
  },
}
```

I had to use `nodemon` to detect changes and restart the node server.

But if your React application need to be started separately from your node application then I suggest using something like `http-server` to start the local server for your React app. And then use `concurrently` to start both applications concurrently.
Your `package.json` may look like the following:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "rollup -c -w",
    "start:client": "http-server ./dist/client/",
    "start:server": "nodemon --ignore '*.ts' --inspect=9000 ./dist/server/index",
    "serve": "concurrently \"npm:start:client\" \"npm:start:server\""
  },
}
```

Resource VS Code debug configuration: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging

Comment: What debug configurations should I have for a VS Code Workspace consisting of a React and Node.js app?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the client requires an `npm start` is because you are referring to http://localhost:3000

npm start will actually run a mini web server to serve up your html files on http://localhost:3000

The other way is to use something like `http-server` on your src, which will have the same effect

Comment: How would that look in a package.json or would it be done in launch.json?

Comment: You can either issue the command from your command line manually, cd into the src folder and then `http-server .` or add an item in the `scripts` section of package.json.

Answer (score 0):

To launch the frontend server at the beginning, you also need to add an additional configuration to run `npm start` for the frontend.

Since your React app is in a subdirectory, you also need to specify the directory containing package.json with --prefix.

You may also wish to disable the browser launched by `npm start` which runs without debugging, and you can do this by specifying `"env": { "BROWSER": "none" }`.

Here's how it can be done in your case:

```json
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"compounds": [
    {
        "name": "Client+Server",
        "configurations": [ "Server", "Client React", "Client" ]
    }
],
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Server",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/server/server.js"
    },
    {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Client",
        "url": "http://localhost:3000",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/client/src/index.js"
    },
    {
        "command": "npm start --prefix ${workspaceFolder}/client",
        "name": "Client React",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "node-terminal",
        "env": { "BROWSER": "none" }
    }
]
}
```

This way, you do not have to use http-server.